# Is it worth to pre-cache templates?

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic framework but I think my question is more generic.

It's a good practice to pre-cache HTML template by means of some grunt/gulp tasks like [html2JS](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-ng-html2js).
The benefit is to reduce the network round trip.

However, what about the case where the web portion is embedded in a smartphone, like Cordova/Phonegap does.

Indeed, there is no involved network.

Should I still pre-cache the templates?

Moreover, in the same context, should I need to uglify my HTML/JS?

I guess the answers are "No" and "No" but any confirmation would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like your phone *is* the cache (i.e. no transmission is taking place).  Ergo, I'd say no.

Comment: Thanks Robert :) If you want, you can transform your comment in an answer so that I validate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed a much improved "first run" experience after using gulp to pre-cache. Even though it's loading templates from the same device, i.e. not the internet, it's still seems to be faster. I used this Gulp task: https://github.com/miickel/gulp-angular-templatecache which just creates a nice module for you to include.

Comment: Interesting :) Will try it now

Comment: You can checkout this post which steered me in the right direction: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/could-i-set-up-ionic-in-such-a-way-that-it-downloads-an-entire-spa-upfront/7565/4 the last reply talks specifically about how to get it all setup.